# Cannot vertical align center an image and text on the same line React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align an image and text vertically on the same line in React Bootstrap:

```
<CardBody 
    className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" 
    style={{borderTop: "1px solid #6c757d", paddingTop: "1rem"}}
>
    <div>
        <p className="text-muted p-0" style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>{subtitle}</p>
    </div>
    <img
        
        src={infoIcon}
        alt="Info"
        style={{width: 20, backgroundColor: 'red', verticalAlign: 'center'}}
    />
</CardBody>
```

However the output is like follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `verticalAlign: 'center'` is not required.

Comment: If I remove this the result is the same. Still doesn't center vertically.

Comment: It could be img might be getting some margins. @Kex

Comment: I tried setting 0 margin and padding on the image and nothing changed.

Comment: You can try setting some smaller width to the img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Bootstrap CSS attached to `<p>` that you are using inside the first `div` that's doing this.

Visit the `p` element in devtools and notice the `margin` it has from Bootstrap:

```
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Override that and it should work.

[Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-dust-m4538?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

you can put them in an element and use flex like:

```js
<div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItem: 'center'}}>
<div>
        <p className="text-muted p-0" style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>{subtitle}</p>
    </div>
    <img
        
        src={infoIcon}
        alt="Info"
        style={{width: 20, backgroundColor: 'red', verticalAlign: 'center'}}
    />
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The result is the same. Items are not correctly centered vertically.